# 非道をつくそうとする translation attempt

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm reading a book, and in this scene, the leader of a Yakuza group is plotting to try to gain the spot as the largest and strongest syndicate in the region. His group has kidnapped 2 characters from the target syndicate, and he's talking with those 2 characters. He previously said that he finds other's misfortunes amusing.

The sentence I'm trying to translate:
あいつの蔭で延々と　非道をつくそうとする　思考も面白いがわしはどちらかというと派手好みでな

My attempt: The thought of [doing something unjust?] in a drawn out way in the shadows is also amusing, but if it were one or the other, I would prefer to be showy/extravagant.

I'm not sure what verb つく translates to. Either one of the many many possibilities of つく verbs with verb root + そう like "to appear/seem to (verb)"? But which つく, there's a lot and they have so many potential meanings.

Comment: Could the verb be 尽くす?

Answer (score 1):

This is 非道を**尽くす**, where 尽くす means "to do (something) fully", "to exhaust" or "to run the full gamut of ～". 非道を尽くす means doing all sorts of atrocious things.

Similar examples:

- 全力を尽くす: to do one's best
- 町で破壊の限りを尽くす:  to run the gamut of destruction in the town